# Parsing Css text and extracting selectors

Tags: javascript, html, css, regex

I'm trying to parse css text and extract from the cssSelectors the elements id's or classes.
so i'm creating a style element inside a `createHTMLDocument("")` so i can inject the cssText and use the node.sheet.cssRules.
now i can reliably extract each selectorText without complicated regex.
but the selectorText can also be quite complicated for example:

```
".some-calss"
".class1> .class2"
".class1 *, .class2 *, .class3 *, .class4 *, .class5 *"
".class1 > .class2.class3"
"div[is="someis"].class4"
```

so i need to reliably extract all id's and classes and if the class or id match my condition i need to replace the id or class of that specific selector and add it to a buffer so i can inject another style tag to the real dom with the modified id's and classes.
any ideas?

EDIT:
so i'm trying to use regex to deal with that but i'm having a lot of trouble . i managed to create something very basic:

```
(?:^|[\.]).*?([^\s]+(?!\.))
```

but if i have got a selector like this:

```
.test-in-out.testclass-2#testclass
```

it will select all of that.
any help?

Comment: Why would you need that? Reads more like a logical flaw to me. You could do it the other way. Give every element a unique style and get all the affected elements by javascript using `getComputedStyle()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: I need it because i'm parsing html from string and i need to change some elements ids and classes so i also need to change the ids and classes in the style tag @Lain

Comment: Cant you just give them all an additional class? Do you have control over that HTML? If not, why do you fetch that "wrong" HTML?

Comment: @Lain  I can give them an additional class but first I need to extract the Id an class of the selector in order to grab the element so I still needs to do exactly what I described , and I don’t fetch the wrong HTML , the HTML is from a third party origin and I would like to add additional style to some elements that I need the Id and class from the selector so again I need to do exactly what I described above

Comment: There are some plugins for that. Like https://github.com/CindyLinz/JS-extract-css-selector